# React Native Image needs to show image on corner

Tags: android, ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, react-native-image

I have an image viewer box in my app box has the size 300px x 300px when I set the image in it and the image has the width and height 100% of this box now I set it resizeMode: 'contain' every image shows in the center of this box, but I need it to show the image in the corner of the box

```
<View style={{
    width: 300,
    height: 300
}}>
    <Image
        source={item.img_url}
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            resizeMode: 'contain'
        }}
    />
</View>
```

Check this attachment the logos of companies have the same height but the width is different and the image is always in the corner I need something like this in my scenario.

[image]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Also an example image of what you want

Comment: Please check I have updated the question.